# Dot initialization struct after malloc

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, struct

I'm trying to allocate a structure with malloc and then initialize it with the dot syntax. I tried some things, but it seems to be impossible.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct t {
  int nb;
};

struct t *foo()
{
  struct t *f = malloc(sizeof(struct t));
  *f = { .nb = 0 };
  return f;
}

int main(void)
{
  printf("%d\n", foo()->nb);
  return 0;
}
```

The compiler says :

```
$ gcc -Wall -Werror -std=c99 -Wextra -pedantic test.c 
test.c:11:8: error: expected expression
  *f = { .nb = 0 };
       ^
1 error generated.
```

I tried the assignation without the dereferencement to make another error, I was expecting an incompatible assignation of pointer and non-pointer variable, but the message was the same.

Do you have some tricks to afford this ?

BR.

Comment: It seems you're trying to use a [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because it's not initialization, strictly speaking, but assignment. You need a valid object expression on the right hand side for it to work, and a brace enclosed initializer is simply not that. But that can be amended rather easily by making the rhs a compound literal:

```
*f = (struct t){ .nb = 0 };
```